# Is there a way to prevent Clang from treating va_list as __va_list_tag?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, abstract-syntax-tree, clang++

For some reason, when I declare variables and functions with va_list types in them, the Clang AST treats them as __va_list_tag internally. This is problematic since the latter is a builtin definition that isn't included in stdarg.h. Is there a way to tell Clang not to replace this?

Here's some example code:

```
#include <cstdarg>
typedef int (*process_args)(va_list args);
void useless_func() {
  process_args useless_fp;
}
```

When I replace the types of declarations with their canonical types, I get the following:

```
#include <cstdarg>
typedef int (*process_args)(va_list args);
void useless_func() {
  int (*useless_fp)(__va_list_tag *);
}
```

I'd ideally like the `__va_list_tag *` part to be replaced with `va_list` so the resulting code can be compiled as C++ code.

Comment: Don't use them. Use variadic templates.

Comment: It needs to replace it because that's how varargs is implemented internally. Why do you care about it?

Comment: I'm trying to refactor declaration types as canonical types, so when I get the canonical type as a string (which uses __va_list_tag), I can't output a type that can be compiled. I thought the issue was treating it as a canonical type, but it doesn't make a difference in how va_list is represented.

Comment: You're trying to write a clang plugin or other clang-based tool, correct?
  If so, please post actual code for the source you're compiling as well as your clang tooling/plugin/whatever code.  [mcve]

Comment: or even just post the smallest source that reproduces the problem for the code you're looking at the AST for and what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: The former might be a bit difficult to condense down into a minimal code sample, so I'll post an example of the latter, and edit this with an example of the former.

Comment: I'm using Clang's ASTConsumer and RecursiveASTVisitor APIs to accomplish this.

Comment: It really can't be compiled?  Or you just mean it's not portable?

Comment: Maybe it's a compatibility issue, but when I try to compile it either with g++ or clang++, I get the error "__va_list_tag has not been declared".

Comment: Small correction: error is "error: ‘__va_list_tag’ was not declared in this scope."